# How to add 'Read' functionality into messaging app using flutter and firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I made messaging app using flutter and firestore. 
I want to add a read function like an existing messaging app, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the message take the document Id, go to your collection and set read to true.

```
await Firestore.instance.collection('messages').document(messageId).update({ read: true});
```

Comment: Hi, I was wondering what would trigger flutter to update isRead to true? If we were to trigger the function only when the user opens the chat screen, then if the user is already on the chat screen when a new message is sent, wouldn't this mean that the function to update isRead to true will not be triggered?

Comment: The navigation to view the message would set it to true. Nothing would trigger it. When you get to the view, in your viewReady or modelReady or initState (if you're using that) would call the function to set your read message to true.